# Why margin collapse it's not applied to the html tag?

Tags: html, css

This is a very basic question, but I have always wonder *why*?

I have this `html` code:

```css
div {
  margin: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  background: papayawhip;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>Hello world!</div>
</body>
```

Margin collapse applies up until the `body` element and stops in the `html` element.

***why?***, It's because the root scope for margin collapse it's the `html`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing It's collapsing margins, just google it

Comment: @Huangism Ofc I did!, but I didn't know how to search about this! thanks tho, I have updated my question, does it make sense?